Are there any plans to carry out more parallax observations using New-Horizons?
In 2020, New Horizons famously carried out observations of Proxima Centauri and Wolf 359 as part of an experiment to observe the parallax difference between Earth and the spacecraft.
Are there any plans to use this method to determine the distance to stars?  I imagine, judging from the quality of images from New Horizons, this would be limited to fairly close stars only.

None are duplicates, some in Astronomy, but they're related and potentially helpful sources of information: What's next for New Horizons? and Distance to Proxima Centauri (Gaia VS New Horizons parallax program) and Can New Horizons be used to measure the distance to Betelgeuse (despite its fickle photocenter)? What's after the Kuiper Belt for New Horizons?

and New Horizons current mission (circa 2021)
